# error Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete

Tags: php, apache

I have php site with a page for uploading files. I have a user that is receiving errors when uploading files, its happening  using `move_uploaded_file` fails and the only thing in the error log is the following:

`(70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: [client ....] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade)`

I ran into the same error before and fixed it with what was mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1058237/1019201), the form was originally redirecting with javascript once the file was uploaded which was interrupting the upload. After fixing that I stopped receiving the error, but it is still happening for this user. The files he is using are only around 75kb, and I only ever ran into it with larger files (around 200MB), which I can still upload now without any issue. I had previously increased the file size limit and read request timeout mentioned in some of the other answers for that same question, so I don't think its an issue with those either given the small size of the file.

After a lot of googling I am still at a loss, someone had asked if the user was using a proxy, and its likely this user is on a VPN, but I didnt see any information on how that could be an issue or how to solve it if it was the case. There was some mention of file chunking causing problems but I am not using that either.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the company the user was working for had some sort of network policy that was interfering, unfortunately I am unsure what it was, but after the user contacted their IT department they were able to resolve the issue.